# LogOn to remote protected site using PHP and cURL

Tags: php, php-curl

I am trying to log on to my company's intranet which is protected by an RSA token. I managed to find out all the necessary data for the log on and it works using this code.

```
    <?php
//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.3.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.1 Safari/604.3.5");

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $var);

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

//Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
//not to print out the results of its query.
//Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
//from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute the request (the login)
$store = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

After the log on I will be logged out instantly. There is set a maximum of 2 hours for a session. How ist that normally set? Where will I find this information in the original site code? I guess it will be stored in a cookie? What do I have to do in order to not being logged out right after the logIn?

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Hey @mentle, if you get it sorted. Please post the correction you made, here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its due to unavailability of SESSION and Cookie info. Eventhough you are getting login success, with very next request to code will check for cookie value generated with login and will check against session value.

So if they won't matched then you will be logged out.

I don't think this code will work for your purpose.